# Can I have the META-INF folder into src/main/resources of a Spring command line application?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, meta-inf

I am working on a batch aplication implemented using Spring.

In this application I found the following structure:

```
BATCH PROJECT
      |
      |
      |------> src/main/java (containing the packages)
      |
      |------> src/main/resources
                      |
                      |----------> META-INF
                                      |
                                      |--------> applicationContext.xml (Spring configuration file)
```

So, as you can see in the previous schema, into the **src/main/resources** I found the **META-INF** folder that contain the **applicationContext.xml** file that contains the Spring configuration (the beans definition).

This batch works fine but I have some doubt: can this place considered the correct place where to put the **applicationContext.xml** file ?

I always see the **META-INF** directory into web application (and not batch application as this) into the following folder that I don't have in this project (because it is not a web application):

```
webapp
|
|_src
|
|_WebContent
  |
  |__WEB-INF
  |
  |__META-INF
```

Is it correct or can I do better?

Answer (score 2):

> This batch works fine but I have some doubt: can this place considered
>   the correct place where to put the applicationContext.xml file ?

Yes, this is fine.  [Here is a Spring Boot example that is doing precisely this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-xml/src/main/resources/META-INF/application-context.xml).

`META-INF` is intended to contain the `MANIFEST.MF` file and the `services` subdirectory related to the `ServiceLoader` class, but other frameworks, including Spring, use it as well.

References:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#The_META-INF_directory

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: Unfortunately the github link is dead. Do you have a similar example?

Answer (score 0):

For Spring-batch it should be located under:

META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/*.xml

So, in your case would be:

WebContent/META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/applicationContext.xml